# Windows 8: Deleted and trying to recover

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery

I have a Lenovo Y500 with OEM installed Windows 8 Enterprise x64 and I accidentally delete the system partition.

I could not find my serial key for Windows. Is there any way to find the serial or install a Windows and use UEFI to get the serial?

I manage to contact the provider and he said that I should get a recovery disc from another user that has the same laptop model (Y500), and attempt to recover my Windows installation. However, I couldn't find another user to get a copy of a Windows recovery disc.

Is there another way to get copy of the Windows recovery / installation disc to recover my system?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You deleted your partition, a recovery disc will not help (or help the way you believe it will). Windows 8 has the Serial number embedded on the PC, just reinstall Windows 8.

Microsoft alway have direct links to their products (just hard to find). 
Here is one for English x64 Enterprise (http://care.dlservice.microsoft.com/dl/download/5/3/C/53C31ED0-886C-4F81-9A38-F58CE4CE71E8/9200.16384.WIN8_RTM.120725-1247_X64FRE_ENTERPRISE_EVAL_EN-US-HRM_CENA_X64FREE_EN-US_DV5.ISO)

Because you have a laptop with Windows 8 pre installed - just install, no key required.

Comment: Hi again, it didn't work every thing was right until it complete installing windows and then the install window appears again unlike the normal installation where it should continue to the user window.